# How to find all the pom.xml files with a given dependency?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml

I have multiple projects with multipe submodules in svn, and I want to find all the artifacts/poms which have a given dependency in terms of groupId::artifactId:version.

Maybe theres is a plugin for that? Or maybe I have to implement it myself, for eks. in perl?

Comment: Can you explain *why* you want to do that? I ask because there may be plugins that can solve your end goal, but not necessarily provide you with the intermediate information.

Comment: @DuncanJones We have hundreds of modules with complex dependencies, and when we "mvn release" for production, we only want to release modules with scm changes. So, given a module X which has some code/config change, I want to find all the modules on which I need to "mvn release", and these are exactly the modules that has X as dependency. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: This can be best solved with a CI solution like Jenkins which can be configured to handle such kind of depenendencies.

Comment: This is hard to trigger the whole rebuild from the "upmost" parent module. Say A depends on B, and B needs to be rebuilt, I don't consider as correct to rebuild B with the same version number, as this is a new version of B. Then, I would rebuild B, incrementing the version and updating the A pom. This might be a bit boring, but I think this is the best approach.